# R is not ordering data correctly - skips E values

Tags: r

I am trying to order data by the column weightFisher. However, it is almost as if R does not process e values as low, because all the e values are skipped when I try to order from smallest to greatest.

Code:

```
resultTable_bon <- GenTable(GOdata_bon,
                           weightFisher = resultFisher_bon,
                           weightKS = resultKS_bon,
                           topNodes = 15136,
                           ranksOf = 'weightFisher'
)
head(resultTable_bon)

#create Fisher ordered df
indF <- order(resultTable_bon$weightFisher)
resultTable_bonF <- resultTable_bon[indF, ]
```

what resultTable_bon looks like:

```
       GO.ID                             Term Annotated Significant Expected Rank in weightFisher
1 GO:0019373         epoxygenase P450 pathway        19          13     1.12                    1
2 GO:0097267   omega-hydroxylase P450 pathway         9           7     0.53                    2
3 GO:0042738 exogenous drug catabolic process        10           7     0.59                    3
  weightFisher weightKS
1      1.9e-12  0.79744
2      7.9e-08  0.96752
3      2.5e-07  0.96336
```

what "ordered" resultTable_bonF looks like:

```
        GO.ID                                        Term Annotated Significant Expected Rank in weightFisher
17 GO:0014075                           response to amine        33           7     1.95                   17
18 GO:0034372 very-low-density lipoprotein particle re...        11           5     0.65                   18
19 GO:0060710                     chorio-allantoic fusion         6           4     0.35                   19
   weightFisher weightKS
17      0.00014  0.96387
18      0.00016  0.83624
19      0.00016  0.92286
```

Comment: Could you provide a [reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) It will be much easier for others to answer your question if they can reproduce your issue.

Comment: read the help for `order` with `?order`.  And use order's argument `decreasing`.  R is doing exactly what you asked it to do.

Comment: I want it to increase. By e value, I mean negative e value. Look at how the first table has very low weightFisher values, but then when I try to order it, in the next table, the lowest terms are not there first.

Comment: How many rows are in "resultTable_bonF"? We can only see rows 17:19, but in those it looks like `weightFisher` is in ascending order. What do you get from `head(resultTable_bonF); tail(resultTable_bonf)`?

Comment: nevermind got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

```
resultTable_bon$weightFisher <- as.numeric (resultTable_bon$weightFisher)
```

Then :

```
resultTable_bonF <- resultTable_bon[order(resultTable_bonF$weightFisher),]
```

Answer (score 1):

As @bhas says, it appears to be working precisely as you want it to. Maybe it's the use of `head()` that's confusing you?

To put your mind at ease, try it with something simpler

```
dtf <- data.frame(a=c(1, 8, 6, 2)^-10, b=c(7, 2, 1, 6))

dtf
             # a b
# 1 1.000000e+00 7
# 2 9.313226e-10 2
# 3 1.653817e-08 1
# 4 9.765625e-04 6

dtf[order(dtf$a), ]
             # a b
# 2 9.313226e-10 2
# 3 1.653817e-08 1
# 4 9.765625e-04 6
# 1 1.000000e+00 7
```